# Entity Framework: Unable to add entry to cross-ref table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In my DB I have the following tables:

```
st_dictionary
    id
    [other fields]

st_language
    id
    [other fields]

st_dictionary_language
    dictionary_id
    language_id
```

When I created the Entity Model of these (and other) tables, the Entity Framework appeared intelligent enough to 'condense' the `st_dictionary_language` cross-referencing table into

```
public partial class st_dictionary
{
    public virtual ICollection<st_language> st_language { get; set; }
    [other members]
}
```

As anticipated, this property is populated with the `st_language` entities which are linked through the cross-referencing table.

However, when I wish to reference another language to this `st_dictionary` entity I run into a problem:

```
daoDictionary.st_language.Add(new st_language { id = newLangID });
```

The above code throws an exception which lists a series of validation errors, each of which explains that some `st_language` properties cannot be null. These non-null properties all exist in the `st_language` DB table, not in the cross-referencing table.

So how do I add a new entry in the `st_dictionary_language` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the actual entity that you wish to cross-reference rather than passing in a new object (which, in your example, you populate with only the `id` property).

Looking at your example, probably something like this:

```
var daoLanguage = [retrieve the st_language entity via the Entity Framework];
daoDictionary.st_language.Add(daoLanguage);
```

Good luck!